# I want to get the SharedPreference data in Multipart class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I Have Store two value in Shared preference now i want to send image file to server and the id i have been stored in shared preference now i want to get access in the multipart class please help me. I have tried adding context too but didnt work for me.As in response i have stored id previously in Shared Pref now i want that nin this class so i want to retrieve it here and pass it as param in volley request.

```
    public class MultiPartRequest extends Request<String> {
    private Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private HttpEntity mHttpEntity;
    public MultiPartRequest(Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener listener, ArrayList<File> file, int numberOfFiles) {
        super(Method.POST, EndPointAPI.PATH, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mHttpEntity = buildMultipartEntity(file, numberOfFiles);
    }
    private HttpEntity buildMultipartEntity(ArrayList<File> file, int numberOffiles) {
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
            SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("ABC", MODE_PRIVATE);
 i have tried 
SharedPreferences prefs1 = mcontext.getSharedPreferences("ABC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String token = prefs1.getString("token", "");
            String aksk_no = prefs1.getString("aksk_no", "");
            Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String strDateFormat = "MM";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
            String strMonth = sdf.format(c);
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yyyy");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c);
            String[] separated = formattedDate.split("/");
            String strYear = separated[1];
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file.get(i));
            builder.addPart("fileToUpload", fileBody);
            builder.addTextBody("a_k_s_no", aksk_no.trim();
            builder.addTextBody("year", strYear);
            builder.addTextBody("month", strMonth);
            builder.addTextBody("token", token.trim();
        }
        builder.addTextBody(Template.Query.KEY_DIRECTORY, Template.Query.VALUE_DIRECTORY);
        builder.addTextBody("numberOfFiles", String.valueOf(numberOffiles));
        return builder.build();
    }@Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return mHttpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
    }
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            mHttpEntity.writeTo(bos);
            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("" + e);
            return null;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            VolleyLog.e("" + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(new String(response.data, "UTF-8"),
                    getCacheEntry());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.success(new String(response.data),
                    getCacheEntry());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do like this,

```
Context context;

public MultiPartRequest(Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener listener, ArrayList<File> file, int numberOfFiles,Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

SharedPreferences prefs1 = context.getSharedPreferences("ABC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Sorry it throws error   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.ashish.manshakti.ui.UploadPics.MultiPartRequest.buildMultipartEntity(MultiPartRequest.java:35)
        at com.ashish.manshakti.ui.UploadPics.MultiPartRequest.<init>(MultiPartRequest.java:30)